# Modified By column Manipulation

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list

Is there is anyway so that the Modified By column is not updated at first when we create it but be updated when modified?

Comment: Could you give some details about what you are trying to achieve?  Why do you wish to prevent the Modified By column being populated?

Comment: I am creating a list for nominating employees for awards.
I have used the 'Created By' column as 'Nominated By'. I need a column which updates the one who approves this nomination.
I was hoping to achieve this by using 'Modified By'. But this column is updated when created and shows the Nominated By and Approved By with same names.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this would be to not worry about the ModifiedBy, (which you should never really mess with default anything in SP) and create you a multiline text field and make it required.  If you append changes to it, SharePoint will put the user below the comment.  Just have them put approved or whatever in the multiline text field and there you go.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new column called 'Approved By'.  Go in the List Settings (assuming you are using a List).  Scroll down the menu and find the option to **Create column**>name your column>The type of information in this column is: Person or Group.

Before you save your new column review the other options on the page, under the heading **Additional Column Settings**.  There is something called 'Choose From' All Users or Groups - you might want to consider making an Approvers group to which you can add the names of your approvers, this will limit the range of possible approvers to what you specify (perhaps managers / supervisors?).

Besides this you might want to make a simple approval Workflow which emails an Approver when something needs their approval.

Comment: With this, the person has to manually type in his/her name as approver in list/Form. right?

Comment: Once you start typing Sharepoint will start making suggestions of names.  The list of names available to my Sharepoint system are based on Active Directory, though it's possible yours is configured differently (I'm no expert on the Active Directory side of things).  Also the names available to you can be determined within the field settings (i.e. your new Approvers group - if you only include 3 names in your Approvers group, there will only be 3 available to choose from).